# How to stop the current playing song after clicking on any other song in ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu-14.04

I have Songs in my listview in QT. On clicking on one song it starts playing but after clicking on other song, both songs starts playing together.
Please give any solution to stop previous song on clicking of other song in ubuntu in QT creator 3.0.1 based on 5.2.

Comment: How do you play the song? Do you use `QMediaPlayer`?

Comment: please explain complete with code example.

Comment: no using gstreamer i play my song @Karsten Koop

Comment: Can we create playlist of songs using gstreamer in cpp i.e. play one song one after another ?

Answer (score 0):

its depend on how you have written code to play music, its seems that you are creating QMediaPlayer memory for each click.